# How to select the next label in jQuery?

Tags: jquery

How to select the label with class="date" and id="z" here from my position?

```
<td style="width:300px;height:40px;" id="pricePanel">
    <div id="class">
        <label class="priceNumber" id="label">test</label>
        <div class="no" hidden="hidden">
            <input type="text" id='priceNumber' class="text" style="text-align:center;" onkeypress="if(event.keyCode==13)" value='@item.Cost.ToString()' />
        </div>
    <div>
</td>
<td id="x">
    <label class="date" id="z">@date</label>
</td>
```

My position is here in textbox block in my jQuery code:

```
$(".text").live("keypress", function (event) {
        //Here I want to change the text of the label with class="date" and id="z"
    });
```

Note:In the main code I have a loop and unfortunately there is some of the labels with the same class and id and because of this I want to select the label after the textbox that I have changed its text.

Comment: In the main code I have a loop and unfortunately there is some of the labels with the same class and id and because of this I want to select the label after the textbox that I have changed its text.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

use `$(this)` reference to get the current position.. `parents('td')` to move to `<td>`..`next()` to get the next `<td>` and `find` to get the label
try this

```
 $("div.no").on("keypress",".text", function (event) {
   $(this).parents('td').next().find('#z').text();
});
```

**HOWEVER** since you have id in the label...using it directly as a selector is better performance wise and faster..

```
 $(".text").on("keypress", function (event) {
   $('#z').text();  // $('label.date').text();
});
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `closest()` to reach the parent `td` of text then use `next()` to reach next td and `find()` label with given class. You probably have repeated structure and use same `id` with more then one element is prohibited so use `class` with label. If you do not have 
repeated structure then use id straight away.

**[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/ZPJpv/)**

You are not close the first div in the first td also.

*Html*

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td style="width:300px;height:40px;" id="pricePanel">
            <div id="class">
                <label class="priceNumber" id="label">test</label>
                <div class="no">
                    <input type="text" id='priceNumber' class="text" style="text-align:center;"
                    onkeypress="if(event.keyCode==13)" value='@item.Cost.ToString()' />
                </div>
            </div>
        </td>
        <td id="x">
            <label class="date" id="z">@date</label>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

*Javascript*

```
$(".text").live("keypress", function (event) {
    $(this).closest('td').next('td').find('.date').text("your text");
});
```

If you do not have repeated block and have single then directly use id.

```
$(".text").live("keypress", function (event) {
    $('#z').text("your text");
});
```

`Live` is deprecated use `on` if it is possible.

Comment: Your answer was true ofcourse but if I could hit the coorect answer sign for 2 answers.Thanks alot.;)

Answer (score 1):

```
   $(".text").live("keypress", function (event) {
             $("label#z").text(/*your text*/)
        });
```

Answer (score 1):

Using ID / class is faster way to identify and object

**Directly use ID property (considering "z" is an unique id)**

```
$('#z').text("your text")
```

**If z is duplicate then better use class**

```
$('label.date').text("your text")
```